# Populate form with a passed value from another form using visual studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have one form with a few Datagridviews which are populated with data from different databases (screenshot 1)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jX9C.jpg)
When I right click a new form pops up which I want to populate with all the data from the row that is selected (screenshot 2)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tT7Yg.jpg)
In my code I hard coded the number 1376 to see if it works. If I replace the number 1376 with ValuePass it won't work. So I need a way to pass that value somehow. It did the same thing for a piece of string which works but it does not seem to work for the value.

So this is what I got so far in my first Form

```
Public Class Relatie_beheer
Public SQL As New SQLControl
Dim value As Object

Private Sub dvgRelaties_CellClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) _
    Handles dgvRelaties.CellClick
    If (e.RowIndex = -1 Or e.ColumnIndex = -1) Then Return

    ' No matter which cell is clicked, put the data from the field in the relatie_nr column in the variable value
    Dim x As Integer
    x = e.ColumnIndex + (3 - e.ColumnIndex)
    value = dgvRelaties.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(x).Value
End Sub

Private Sub WijzigenToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles WijzigenToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Dim Obj As New RelatieNieuw With {
        .StringPass = "Wijzigen"
    }
    Dim ValObj As New RelatieNieuw With {
        .ValuePass = value
    }
    Obj.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

And in my second Form

```
Public Class RelatieNieuw
Public SQL As New SQLControl
Public Property StringPass As String
Public Property ValuePass As String

Private Sub RelatieNieuw_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Label2.Text = StringPass + " Relatie"
    Select Case StringPass
        Case "Toevoegen"
            ' Open new window and create a new private key number
        Case "Wijzigen"
            ' Open new window and retrieve relatie fields to change
            SQL.AddParam("@item", 1376)
            SQL.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM relatie WHERE Relatie_nr = @item;")
            txtzoeknaam.Text = SQL.DBDT.Rows(0)(1).ToString

        Case "Verwijder"
            ' Open new window and retrieve relatie fields to delete
        Case Else
            MsgBox("Option not defined " + StringPass)
    End Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed it myself in the following way:

In the first form I changed the code to this:

```
    Dim value As Object

    Private Sub WijzigenToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles WijzigenToolStripMenuItem.Click
      Dim Obj As New RelatieNieuw("Wijzigen", value)
      Obj.ShowDialog()
    End Sub
```

And my second form looks like this now:

```
Public Class RelatieNieuw
Public SQL As New SQLControl
Public Property StringPass As String
Dim ValuePass As String

Public Sub New(ByVal pstr As String, ByVal value As String)
    ' This call Is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    StringPass = pstr
    ValuePass = value
End Sub
```

and instead of the 1376 i have ValuePass

Seems to work now.

Comment: Yes, that is basically the same as the solution I mentioned.
I forgot a comma in the above code. I edited the original post.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating 2 different RelatieNieuw-objects, while that should be 1 object with 2 params:

```
Dim Obj As New RelatieNieuw With {
    .StringPass = "Wijzigen",
    .ValuePass = value
}
```

'yeah: forgot the comma

Comment: If I do that I get an error. It expects an } after "Wijzigen"